# mysql - How to add a counter to a column?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have events each with 50 maximum participants.

Every time a user signs up for an event, his name, email, and mobile no. gets saved in the database. So I am inserting these values whenever a sign up is made: `ID, p_name, p_mobile, p_email, p_event` the last column is the name of the event.

**I need to add a new column called `p_max` wherein it will automatically increase by 1 for each unique event. A sort of counter.**

So I can then check if the maximum is reached by getting the p_max column of the last row with the event name.

I hope I explained the question clearly. Feel free to ask questions for clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you would need to check for the number of users for a specific event before you confirm the sign-up.

So you would not need a new column (or it would be a column in the events table where you can specify the maximum number of participants per event), you need to check how many users there already are for that specific event.

You could use something like this to query the database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_participants FROM users WHERE p_event = YOUR_EVENT_ID
```

Comment: Yes. But I can do that if I have the count for **each** event.

Comment: @user2772219 I'm not sure what you mean, you are talking about a fixed number of 50 and this count is per event.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want an events table, that has the maximum number of participants.

Then you need a before insert trigger on the participants table.  This trigger would fail if the following is true:

```
select (count(*) >= max(e.maxparticipants))
from participants p join
     events e
     on p.event = e.event
where event = new.event;
```

These will limit the number of participants in an event.

You can also implement this in a stored procedure rather than a trigger, if you wrap your `insert` logic in stored procedures.

Or, you can implement this logic directly in your application, although I think it is safer to implement it in the database.  If you do so, consider this statement:

```
insert into participants(<columns go here>)
    select <column values go here>
    from dual
    where (select max(e.maxparticipants) - COUNT(*))
           from participants p join
                events e
                on p.event = e.event
           where event = THEEVENT
          ) > 0;
```

This insert will not insert any rows once the maximum has been reached.